# Blender opens different image than I select?

Tags: image, shader-nodes

So I have an image node in shader view. When I click x on that image and try to open different image it opens the original image. No matter what I do I can't get blender to open the image I want?! For example I have an image there called grass1a.png. I press x and try to open image called grass2a.png. I open that image and blender just puts grass1a.png there.

I can't even open the grass2a.png in the blender image editor. It always opens grass1a.png instead...?

What on earth could cause this? I'm totally stuck on this ridiculous issue. I can't post the blend sorry.

Comment: Hi :). Could this be a similar case? [Blender displays wrong image, when opening a second different image](https://developer.blender.org/T79627)

Comment: No I don't think so. I've tried restarting blender and I have not changed the file names outside of blender. I have not moved the images around between folders or replaced or done anything to them. Blender literally opens grass1a.png when I try to open grass2a.png. It is the filename of grass1a.png and the contents of that too. For some reason blender just doesn't open grass2a.png.

Comment: and can it open another image ? so we can figure out if the problem came from the picture grass2a.png specifically

Comment: Yes, it seems to open other images fine. There is also nothing wrong with the image blender refuses to open. It works fine in gimp for example. It seems some weird issue with the name as the same image opens fine if I name it zzz.png for example.

Comment: I'd be happy if anybody could just spitball random ideas. I'm willing to experiment to get rid of this stupid thing.

Comment: Something something something... closed blender, moved the image in other folder and now it opens normally.